# Sometimes getting: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, base64, nuxt.js

So I am working on my imageupload component to upload a profile image as base64 string to the Rails API backend. Everything is working fine so far but sometimes I am getting the following error:

'Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.'

This is my code:

**Javascript Function to select and encode the image**

```js
selectImage(e) {
      const selectedImage = e.target.files[0] // get image
      this.createBase64Image(selectedImage)
    },

    createBase64Image(fileObject) {
      const reader = new FileReader()

      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.form.profile_image = e.target.result
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject)
    }
```

HTML

```html
                <div class="flex items-center">
                          <div
                            class="object-cover object-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-100 rounded-full w-14 h-14"
                          >
                            <img style="" :src="form.profile_image" alt="" />
                            <svg
                              v-if="form.profile_image == null"
                              class="w-full h-full text-gray-300"
                              fill="currentColor"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            >
                              <path
                                d="M24 20.993V24H0v-2.996A14.977 14.977 0 0112.004 15c4.904 0 9.26 2.354 11.996 5.993zM16.002 8.999a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"
                              />
                            </svg>
                          </div>
                          <input
                            type="file"
                            accept="image/*"
                            class="custom-input-button"
                            @change="selectImage"
                          />
                        </div>
```

A possibility could be that this error somehow only occurs when I hot reload the page after a small change in the file.

**EDIT**

The error is solved. After you choose a picture and want to choose a different picture, you cant press cancel since this will trigger the error because it will change to "no file chosen". So you will need to put the reader.readAsDataURL within an If statement.

Comment: If you are converting it as a base64 format, you don't need to pass it as a file object, you can send it as a string

And the reason it is failing is also because you are formatting it

Comment: What's the value of fileObject when the error happens?

Comment: @ArjunKanungo Well, it is a string right? This is my output: https://i.gyazo.com/3434721c95adf0beba348ec52c3aea0c.png

Comment: @LajosArpad I see what triggers this error. When I open up the filepicker after I already chosen an image this error will come up when I cancel/close the filepicker instead of choosing a different picture. Have you any idea what I should change to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the value you have as input is a blob:

```
selectImage(e) {
  const selectedImage = e.target.files[0]; // get image
  if (selectedImage instanceof Blob) {
    this.createBase64Image(selectedImage);
  } else {
    //not a blob, cancel/close happened
  }
},
```

and in the else branch you can do some handling for the case when cancel/close occurred